# Chance $U_1$is bigger than all other random variables

Tags: probability, optimization

Please, help with the following would be highly appreciated. Again, I have an idea and a solution, but would like to see what other people think. 
Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_N$ be iid random variables drawn from $F(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}$. Define $U_i=X_i+\delta_i$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots N\}$, where $\delta_i$'s are constants. What is the probability that $U_1=max_i\{U_i\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\prod_{i=2}^{N}{F(x+\delta_1-\delta_i)}\mathrm{d}F(x)}$

=$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\prod_{i=2}^{N}{e^{-e^{-(x+\delta_1-\delta_i)}}}e^{-x}e^{-e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x}$

=$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-e^{-x}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{e^{-(\delta_1-\delta_i)}}}e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x}$

$=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{e^{-(\delta_1-\delta_i)}}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\mathrm{d}e^{-e^{-x}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{e^{-(\delta_1-\delta_i)}}}}$

$=\frac{e^{\delta_1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{e^{\delta_i}}}$